# Rearrange and merge a dataset of sequences based on days

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I am working on a dataset where people had to fill activities for two days.

Questionnaire 1 was designed to capture day 1 and questionnaire 2 for day 2. 
But some respondents filled day 2 in questionnaire 1 and day 1 in questionnaire 2.

So basically what I want is to rearrange and merge (or merge and rearrange) the data in order to have day 1 first and day 2 afer for every respondents.

```
seq1 = as.data.frame( rbind(c(1, 1, 1, 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), 
                            c(2, 1, 1, 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd'), 
                            c(3, 1, 2, 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a'), 
                            c(4, 1, 2, 'c', 'a', 'b', 'e'))) 
colnames(seq1) <- c('id', 'quest', 'day', paste('act',1:4))

seq2 = as.data.frame( rbind(c(1, 2, 2, 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd'), 
                            c(2, 2, 2, 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), 
                            c(3, 2, 1, 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c'), 
                            c(4, 2, 1, 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c') )) 
colnames(seq2) <- c('id', 'quest', 'day', paste('act',1:4))

# seq1
   id quest day act 1 act 2 act 3 act 4
1  1     1   1     a     a     b     c
2  2     1   1     a     a     b     d
3  3     1   2     c     d     b     a    # Mistake here 
4  4     1   2     c     a     b     e    # Mistake here 

# seq 2
   id quest day act 1 act 2 act 3 act 4
1  1     2   2     a     a     b     d
2  2     2   2     c     a     b     c
3  3     2   1     a     d     b     c    # Mistake here 
4  4     2   1     d     a     b     c    # Mistake here
```

So I would like to merge my data in order to put day 1 and day 2 following each others.

```
merge(seq1, seq2, by = 'id', suffixes = c('_day1', '_day2'))
```

I would like to have a dataset looking like this but with the correct rearranging of the days.

```
  id quest_day1 day_day1 act 1_day1 act 2_day1 act 3_day1 act 4_day1 quest_day2     day_day2 act 1_day2 act 2_day2 act 3_day2 act 4_day2
1  1          1        1          a          a          b          c                2        2          a          a          b          d
2  2          1        1          a          a          b          d                2        2          c          a          b          c
3  3          1        2          c          d          b          a                2        1          a          d          b          c
4  4          1        2          c          a          b          e                2        1          d          a          b          c
```

I am sure that there is a simple solution with dplyr to rearrange the dataframe.

Any solution ?

Comment: You may want to add your desired result to the question - it's unclear to me what you want.

Comment: If you change your example to `paste0` instead of `paste` you'll have legal R variable names to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `dplyr`, and `merge` is not the right tool for this job. Just `rbind` your datasets, then sort them.

```
all.data <- rbind(seq1, seq2)
all.data <- all.data[order(all.data$day),]
```